# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, word2vec

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use ('ggplot')

from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

from gensim.test.utils import datapath, get_tmpfile
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
from gensim.scripts.glove2word2vec import glove2word2vec

glove_file = datapath('c:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt')
word2vec_glove_file = get_tmpfile("glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt")
glove2word2vec(glove_file, word2vec_glove_file)
```

I am trying to use Glove vector. But it is yielding a syntax error like below:

```
File "<ipython-input-27-b7974d8ef44b>", line 1
    glove_file = datapath('\Users\Lenovo\AppData\glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt')
                          ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using / in the address it would solve the problem. So you should write /Users/Lenovo/AppData/glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt

I worked on my end.

If this doesn't work try //

Best

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
glove_file = datapath(r'c:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\glove.6B.100d.word2vec.txt')
```

You have to read the path...
It'll Solve your problem...

Comment: I have actually tried as you have advised but it did not help.